# Does iterating over a Guava LoadingCache's map-view entry set reset the access time used for expiration?

Tags: java, guava

I have a [`LoadingCache<K,V>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) created using a [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html):

```
LoadingCache<K,V> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterAccess(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .maximumSize(500)
    .build(someCacheLoader);
```

I need to periodically iterate over all of the entries (keys and values) in the cache. I know I can accomplish that using [`LoadingCache#asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#asMap--), and either:

- iterate over that map view's [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), or
- iterate over just the [`Map#keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29), and explicitly [`Map#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) the values.

In the former case:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : myCache.asMap().entrySet()) {
    K key = entry.getKey();
    V value = entry.getValue();

    doSomeWorkOn(key, value);
}
```

Will this update the access time of every entry in the cache? I've read the JavaDoc for [`CacheBuilder#expireAfterAccess(long, TimeUnit)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterAccess-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) pretty closely, but have found it to be ambiguous/unclear in this case:

> Specifies that each entry should be automatically removed from the cache once a fixed duration has elapsed after the entry's creation, the most recent replacement of its value, or its last access. Access time is reset by all cache read and write operations (including `Cache.asMap().get(Object)` and `Cache.asMap().put(K, V)`), but not by operations on the collection-views of `Cache.asMap`.

Clearly, the second way of iterating that I mentioned *does* reset the access time, but I'd like to know what the behavior is using the first way.

Comment: So, have you looked at the sources?

Comment: @NiklasB. not yet. It's been a very long day, and the rabbit hole is a bit deep for me right now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would interpret this:

> (...) but not by operations on the collection-views of Cache.asMap

to refer to `entrySet`, `keySet`, and `values`.  Those are the three collection views of a `Map`.  Therefore utilizing them should not result in an access.

Here are JUnit (+Mockito) tests that show the behaviour in each case.  Reading the value through `entrySet` or `values` does **not** prevent the entry from being removed (nor does reading the key from `entrySet` or `keySet`).  Reading using `asMap().get()` does count as an access, as the docs specify.

### Setup

```
private Ticker ticker = Mockito.mock(Ticker.class);

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
private RemovalListener<String, String> removalListener = Mockito.mock(RemovalListener.class);

private Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .removalListener(removalListener)
            .ticker(ticker)
            .build();
```

### `entrySet`

```
@Test
public void testEntrySetAccessDoesNotCountAsAccess() {
    //write
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(0));
    cache.put("foo", "bar");

    //read
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(4));
    cache.asMap().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
    cache.asMap().entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();

    //maintenance
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(6));
    cache.cleanUp();

    verify(removalListener).onRemoval(Mockito.<RemovalNotification<String,String>>any());
}
```

### `keySet`

```
@Test
public void testKeySetAccessDoesNotCountAsAccess() {
    //write
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(0));
    cache.put("foo", "bar");

    //read
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(4));
    cache.asMap().keySet().iterator().next();

    //maintenance
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(6));
    cache.cleanUp();

    verify(removalListener).onRemoval(Mockito.<RemovalNotification<String,String>>any());
}
```

### `values`

```
@Test
public void testValuesAccessDoesNotCountAsAccess() {
    //write
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(0));
    cache.put("foo", "bar");

    //read
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(4));
    cache.asMap().values().iterator().next();

    //maintenance
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(6));
    cache.cleanUp();

    verify(removalListener).onRemoval(Mockito.<RemovalNotification<String,String>>any());
}
```

### `asMap().get()`

```
@Test
public void testMapGetAccessCountsAsAccess() {
    //write
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(0));
    cache.put("foo", "bar");

    //read
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(4));
    cache.asMap().get("foo");

    //maintenance
    when(ticker.read()).thenReturn(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(6));
    cache.cleanUp();

    verify(removalListener, never()).onRemoval(Mockito.<RemovalNotification<String,String>>any());
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct; the access time is not updated.  (I maintain `com.google.common.cache`.)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you, and @LouisWasserman thanks for confirming based on your particularly privileged knowledge.

Comment: I read the source code. Yes, the answer is right. You can find the code here (asMap().get()): http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#2815 and here (getValue() and getKey()): http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#4454

Comment: Hi Is there any way to iterate through LoadingCache(String, List[String]) as scala collection, e.g. for ((k,v) <-cache.asMap.entrySet.asScala) ?

Comment: Sorry for my dummy prev question, of course it might look like                     
           for((k,v) <-cache.asMap.asScala)....